# A question about choosing a fixed voltage method for logic level input of an IC

Tags: integrated-circuit

If [an IC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14611.pdf) is gonna be used in the following scheme, and also needs lets say a fixed 5V logic voltage input to one of its pins VL:

[image]

In these cases should one use a regulated voltage such as diode or voltage reference or would a voltage divider work fine?

What should be the way or parameters to consider when choosing the type of thw reference voltage in such cases? What can be the disadvantage to use a voltage divider with big resistor values (like obtaining 5V from a 10V supply with two 100k resistors)?

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet it is clear (see the application diagram) that VL needs to be connected to the **supply voltage** of the Low voltage logic circuits.

It is up to you how you make that low voltage supply and it is also up to you to make that supply such that it is stable enough to make all the circuits running on it work in a stable way.

In practice almost every designer would simply use a **voltage regulator** (or a voltage from a regulated supply) for that as other solutions result in a less stable supply (voltage divider) and/or are just inefficient (voltage divider and zenerdiode solutions waste energy). Also a decent voltage regulator is so cheap these days that it would be silly not to use one as it has so much benefits.

You should simply **forget** about using a resistor based voltage divider to make the voltages for this IC. It is not designed to be used like that. It is designed to work from the supply voltages which you already should have available in your design.